# Replace a text color by a background image on mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fonts

I would like to know if it's possible to replace a text's color by a background picture.
I don't think that can be done using CSS only, but I'm looking for any other way to do that without using png pictures for the text.
The idea is to keep the background image visible on the font only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its really not that easy...

*Safari and Chrome* offer the property `-webkit-mask-image` which accomplishes exactly what you want but is not supported by any web browser other than Safari and Chrome... read about it [here](http://trentwalton.com/2011/05/19/mask-image-text/).

However, there is this alternate "trick"...

### [Pure CSS Text Gradient](http://cssglobe.com/lab/textgradient/)

I don't exactly *recommend* it but I guess you can't really go wrong, the only problem is when you have other elements on the same line as the text, because this gradient will cut right through the page... If these are suitable, writing the JavaScript would be fairly easy but the CSS Text Background Image in it self is quite the question.

Answer (score 0):

1) Using css3 -webkit-background-clip: text; - But only works in chrome & safari

```
 #p:hover{
   background:transparent url(http://www.astrosurf.com/~buil/iris/new540/gradient1.jpg);
   -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KHECk/2/

2) Using absolute position. It will work in all browsers. But have to check with your requirement. Not work with all kind of images.

http://jsfiddle.net/KHECk/9/

3) You can use SVG also to generate this effect

http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/svg/pattern-fill.svg

Comment: Its not an exam to copy your answer and put there. In Your answer you sated to use -webkit-mask-image. That is wrong & we have to use background clip to make the effect & also "pure css gradient" what to do this title with OP question. Because of these reasons I didn't check the link. Please remove the -ev mark. User have to understand the answer quickly.

Comment: Also you given a wrong url. This is the correct one - http://trentwalton.com/2010/03/24/css3-background-clip-text/